# How to fix "read-line: undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition" in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Im writing a Scheme guessing game and I am getting the error given in the title. There are probably more errors through out the program. Any help is appreciated. I will have the whole entire program below.

```
(#%require (lib "27.ss" "srfi"))

  (define (guess-game target attempts)
    (display "Guess a number from 1 to 100:")
    (newline)
    (let loop ((attempts-left attempts)
               (low 1)
               (high 100))
      (if (= attempts-left 0)
          (begin
            (display "Out of attempts. The correct number was ")
            (display target)
            (newline)
            (display "Please enter your name:")
            (newline)
            (let ((name (read-line)))
              (display "Good game, ")
              (display name)
              (newline)
              (newline)
              (+ (random 99) 1) 1))))
          (begin
            (display "Enter guess ")
            (flush-output)
            (let ((guess (string->number (read-line))))
              (if (not (integer? guess))
                  (begin
                    (display "Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
                    (newline)
                    (loop attempts-left low high)))
                  (if (= guess target)
                      (begin
                        (display "Correct! ")
                        (display attempts)
                        (display " guesses... Please enter your name:")
                        (newline)
                        (let ((name (read-line)))
                          (display "Good game, ")
                          (display name)
                          (newline)
                          (newline)
                          (+ (random 99) 1) 1)))
                      (if (< guess target)
                          (begin
                            (display "Lower...")
                            (newline)
                            (loop (- attempts-left 1) guess high))
                          (begin
                            (display "Higher...")
                            (newline)
                            (loop (- attempts-left 1) low guess))))))
  
(guess-game 100 5)
```

Im not sure how to define it, but here is the output that I have
"Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.10 [cs].
Language: R5RS; memory limit: 128 MB.
Guess a number from 1 to 100:
Enter guess . . read-line: undefined;
cannot reference an identifier before its definition"

Answer (score 0):

Racket has a [`read-line` function](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._read-line%29%29), but it's not provided by the [R5RS language](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/index.html).

You can import it with `(#%require (only racket/base read-line))`.

You're also requiring [SRFI-27](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-27/srfi-27.html) (Better written as `(#%require srfi/27)`), but it doesn't have a `random` function - though Racket, again, does. Import it too (And any other non-R5RS Racket functions you might use later) with

```
(#%require (only racket/base read-line random))
```

There's another big problem with your code, though - you try to use the named `let`'s `loop` outside of the body of the `let`. Should be able to fix that easily if you look at where the closing parenthesis are.

Comment: Another suggestion: Use `cond` instead of nested `if`s + `begin`s.

Comment: `flush-output` also isn't in R5RS but is provided by Racket's r5rs lang anyways.